# PHPExcel date export format

Tags: phpexcel

need some date to be exported from MySql to Excel,
source date format: 2016-11-02,
target date format: 02.11.2016, so
try:

```
->setCellValue("T{$pRow}", (empty($meter['test_date'])) ? '':(new \DateTime($meter['test_date']))->format('d.m.Y'))
```

then, read in the cell '02.11.2016 - date with leading quote

Comment: Or convert the MySQL date to an Excel serialized timestamp, and use a date format mask

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (empty($meter['test_date'])) {
            $objDoc->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("T{$pRow}", '');
        } else {
            \PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new \PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder());
            $objDoc->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("T{$pRow}", $meter['test_date']);
            $objDoc->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("T{$pRow}")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("dd.mm.yyyy");
        }
        if (empty($meter['filling_date'])) {
            $objDoc->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("U{$pRow}", '');
        } else {
            \PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new \PHPExcel_Cell_AdvancedValueBinder());
            $objDoc->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("U{$pRow}", $meter['filling_date']);
            $objDoc->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("U{$pRow}")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode("dd.mm.yyyy");
        }
        $objDoc->getActiveSheet()
```

thanks Mark, I got it